# Deleting user by username (SQL)

Tags: mariadb

I've seen quite a few questions about deleting SQL users by username regardless of host, it seems to me that querying the user.sys table for the host names then explicitly using revoke and drop is the correct answer.

But this question isn't about how to do it properly. (that would rightfully be a duplicate)

I was wondering why this is not the correct answer. (I'm sure I'm going to trigger someone)

DON'T DO THIS!
`DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE user = "bad_user";`
DON'T DO THIS!

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of the DBMS, it is not safe to manipulate system catalog (data dictionary) tables, including `mysql.user`, directly, because you do not necessarily know *what tables exactly* are modified, and how exactly they are modified, when you execute the DDL statements, such as `DROP USER`, that would normally update them. Fine, it used to be OK to `DELETE FROM mysql.user`, but this is not guaranteed to remain so. Just like you do not `DELETE FROM mysql.tables` instead of using `DROP TABLE`.

More mature DBMSes do not even allow you to manipulate the system catalog, keeping it read-only.

Comment: Can you please explain more about "because you do not necessarily know what tables exactly are modified, and how exactly they are modified". Is mysql.user not a specific table? is delete not a specific modification? Or are you referring to other operations that occur when `DROP USER` is executed?

Comment: @Philippe: In later versions of MariaDB, `mysql.user` is actually a view (which maps on to an actual table, `mysql.global_priv`), not a table itself. And while you might still be able to delete from that view, and it might work successfully, in some cases it won't. For example, in MariaDB Galera Clusters, DML statements for non-InnoDB tables (like `mysql.global_priv`) are not replicated.